# How combine sentences based on words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset consisting of words and tags columns. I want to add a sentence column where each word within 1 sentence is separated by a period. How to do it? Here's a snippet from my dataset :

[image: Dataset]

this is the code to load my dataset :

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('sample_data/SINGGALANG.tsv', sep='\t',error_bad_lines=False, engine="python", header = None, names = ['token', 'entitas bernama'], usecols = [0,1])
print(dataset.head())
```

output :

[image: Output]

i wanna make like this :

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: How is your data represented? List of words, or some sort of Pandas table?

Comment: some sort of Pandas table

Comment: Then please add those pandas table _as Code_.

Comment: dataset = pd.read_csv('sample_data/SINGGALANG.tsv', sep='\t',error_bad_lines=False, engine="python", header = None, names = ['token', 'entitas bernama'], usecols = [0,1])
print(dataset.head())

Comment: @Sarada Please **edit** your question with that. Don't forget code block

Comment: And add an excerpt of the actual data, too.

Comment: @tobias_k  huuum, okayyyy